# Callback function created in custom react hook isn't being provided with an up to date value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In a custom alert system I have created in react I have 2 main functions, a custom hook:

```
function useAlerts(){
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  let add = function(content){
    let remove = function(){
      console.log(`alerts was set to ${alerts} before remove`);
      setAlerts(alerts.slice(1));
    };

    let newAlert = 
    <div className = 'alert' onAnimationEnd = {remove} key = {count}>
      <Warning/>
      <span>
        {content}
      </span>
    </div>


    setAlerts([...alerts, newAlert]);
    setCount(count + 1);
  }

  return [alerts,add];
}
```

and another element to display the data within the custom hook.

```
function Alerts(){
  let [alerts,add] = useAlerts();

  useEffect(() => {
    let handler = function(){
      add('test');
    };
    window.addEventListener('keyup',handler);
    return function(){
      window.removeEventListener('keyup',handler);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className = 'alerts'>
      {alerts}
    </div>
  )
}
```

the current issue I have is with the remove callback function, the console will look something like this.

```
let remove = function(){
      console.log(`alerts was set to ${alerts} before remove`);
      /// expected output: alerts was set to [<div>,<div>,<div>,<div>] before remove
      /// given output: alerts was set to [] before remove
      setAlerts(alerts.slice(1));
};
```

I understand this is because the remove function is taking the initial value of the alert state, but how do I make sure it keeps an up to date value? React doesn't seem to allow useEffect in a callback so I seem to be a bit stuck. Is passing the value in an object the way to go or something?

Comment: The problem is that you calling the hook in different places? You have to useContext for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I believe I see here is that of stale enclosures over the local React state. Use [functional state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to correctly update from the previous state instead of whatever if closed over in callback scope. In fact, use functional state updates *any time* the next state *depends* on the previous state's value. Incrementing counts and mutating arrays are two ***prime*** examples for needing functional state updates.

```
function useAlerts() {
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const add = (content) => {
    const remove = () => {
      console.log(`alerts was set to ${alerts} before remove`);
      setAlerts(alerts => alerts.slice(1));
    };

    const newAlert = (
      <div className='alert' onAnimationEnd={remove} key={count}>
        <Warning/>
        <span>
          {content}
        </span>
      </div>
    );

    setAlerts(alerts => [...alerts, newAlert]);
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  }

  return [alerts, add];
}
```